# Get Element By using Class name

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, gwt

I want Element by using class name

Now I am using GWT 2.0

Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName

e: not supported natively in IE < 9, so you'd have to extend document / make a global function with something like this: http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/ or use something like [sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) or [jquery](http://jquery.com) - thanks to comments below.

Comment: Looks like we are being promised support in IE9.

Answer (score 14):

A number of solutions have been built to work around browsers that don't have native `getElementsByClassName`. If you use any of the modern javascript libraries (e.g. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/)), they will automatically spackle over these browser-specific gaps.

So, for example, with jQuery:

```
$('.foo').get();
```

returns all the DOM elements with class `foo`, in any browser.

If you only want this particular problem solved, and don't want to use a full library, you can try using something like [The Ultimate GetElementsByClassName](http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/), which lets you have:

```
getElementsByClassName('foo')
```

Although it's a couple of years old, [John Resig's comparison of various solutions](http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-speed-comparison/) to the problem is still valuable.

Answer (score 3):

Use GwtQuery:
http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/

Answer (score 2):

It may be wiser to use `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll`, supported since IE8.

Have a look here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector
https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll