# set height of the div by using class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am having a div with a class name not having that id.

i need to set that div with browser window height usig Javascript or jquery..

```
<div class="abc"> 

some content

</div>
```

how i set height of the div?..

Comment: Wait.. did you mean browser inner height?

Comment: Possibly duplicate on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478942/get-element-by-using-class-name - Is recommended to use a library like jQuery because IE doesn't support this kind of selection with pure js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with jQuery and .height():

Specific height of 100px:

```
$('.abc').height(100);
```

For browser inner height, do:

```
$('.abc').height(window.innerHeight);
```

Comment: No ! `.height( value )`. `value` = An integer representing the number of pixels, or an integer with an optional unit of measure appended (as a string). Read documentation : http://api.jquery.com/height/

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.abc').height($(window).height());
```

To make that responsive to changes in the browser height, do:

```
$(window).on('resize load', setHeight);

function setHeight() {
    $('.abc').height($(window).height());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('.abc').height(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var height = $(window).height();
  $(".abc").height(height);
});
```

Also make change in css -

```
.abc{
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Used to css as like this

```
html, body{
height:100%;
}
.abc{
height:100%;
}
```

[**[Live demo][1]**](http://tinkerbin.com/G7reQsVP)