# onmouseover="this.style... is working but I need something like onmouseover="this.child.child

Tags: javascript, html

Should be verry easy but I can't get it to work. As described in the title I would like to change onmouseover the background-color from span.name (orange)

```
<div class="pdf-icon-box" style="position:relative;" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'"; onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor = 'green'"; >
    <span class="pdf-style">
        <span class="name" style="display:inline-block;background-color:orange;"> T E S T </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I found this but coul'd not get it to work
[Get Element By using Class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478942/get-element-by-using-class-name)

This is what I'm trying: [fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/8Y6YD/)

It only has to work in FF

Thanks for help!

Comment: @steve no it doesn't. I want the orange color "TEST" to change

Comment: why don't you just use css? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

Comment: Yep got it now see my answer.

Comment: @magritte :hover doesn't work (it is a touch screen) please don't ask me why but onmouseover does work

Comment: oh - well then yeah hover isn't relevant for a touch device. not sure what the ux is that requires you to add hover then? are you maybe looking for :active ? i.e. when they actually press the element with their finger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying your code

```
<div class="pdf-icon-box" style="position:relative;" onmouseover="this.getElementsByClassName('name')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'"; onmouseout="this.getElementsByClassName('name')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'green'"; >
    <span class="pdf-style">
        <span class="name" style="display:inline-block;background-color:orange;"> T E S T </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gwWju/2/)

Comment: There's a great site called Stack Overflow where a bunch of people have asked that same question.  But seriously, folks, try http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for something like this:

```
onmouseover="this.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].style.background='green'";
```

This is pretty ugly though, a better solution is

```
span.name:hover {
    background:green;
}
```

in CSS.

---

To explain the JS, in case it helps:

```
this.childNodes
```

gets a list of all the children of `this`.

The first one at index `[0]` is a text node (the linebreak).

The second one, at index `[1]` is the span you're looking for.

Then, do the same for that span.

Comment: I thought about suggesting css, the problem with the css bases solution is when the mouse leaves the green color doesn't stay. on mouse over it is yellow, on leave it should be green not the initial color

Comment: Also note that although the span is not the div's `firstChild` in Javascript, it would be a `:first-child` in CSS. Because CSS counts only elements, while Javascript also counts text nodes.

Comment: Fair enough.  Looks to me like OP wanted over/out effect (hover) but no biggie.

Comment: Thank you Steve for the explanation! because it is on a touch screen :hover doesn't work but mouseover does (don't ask me why). I would have loved to use :hover.. Thanks!

Comment: Note also that `getElementsByClassName()` is unsupported until IE 9.0 :( maybe not a problem in your case though.

Comment: Oh also if you want to avoid the 'text node' thing I described, jam your tags together with no line breaks, like `<span><span><span>`.

Comment: Instead of `childNodes[1]`, would be better if you use `firstElementChild`

Comment: @Steve totally missed that

Answer (score 2):

You may also try this

```
window.onload = function(){
    var span = document.querySelector('.name');
    // if you want to change the color to change onload
    span.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    span.onmouseover = function(){
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    };
    span.onmouseout = function(){
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    };
};
```

Just put the code between your `<head>` tags like this

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       // code goes here
    </script>
</head>
```

[**Example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/gwWju/3/)

Answer (score 1):

a SPACE is a child. so if u have spaces between    u can't get it.

one way is to write the code without spaces and use firstChild

```
<div class="pdf-icon-box" style="position:relative;" onmouseover="this.firstChild.firstChild.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'"; onmouseout="this.firstChild.firstChild.style.backgroundColor = 'green'"; ><span class="pdf-style"><span class="name" style="display:inline-block;"> T E S T </span></span></div>
```

second way is to use the childNodes[childelement] again : a space/tab/new line is a child

```
<div class="pdf-icon-box" style="position:relative;" onmouseover="this.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'"; onmouseout="this.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].style.backgroundColor = 'green'"; ><span class="pdf-style"><span class="name" style="display:inline-block;"> T E S T </span></span></div>
```

third way is to use the className

```
<div class="pdf-icon-box" style="position:relative;" onmouseover="this.getElementsByClassName('name')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'"; onmouseout="this.getElementsByClassName('name')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'green'"; >
 <span class="pdf-style">
  <span class="name" style="display:inline-block;"> T E S T </span>
 </span>
</div>
```

but thats not a nice way to do that.
use css

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<style>
.name{background-color:yellow;}
.name:hover{background-color:green;}
</style>
<body>
<div class="pdf-icon-box" style="position:relative;">
 <span class="pdf-style">
  <span class="name"> T E S T </span>
 </span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @ArunPJohny, you'd better use CSS.

```
.pdf-icon-box:hover .name {
    background-color: orange;
}
.pdf-icon-box .name {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why don't you use jquery.

```
$(".pdf-icon-box").hover(function(){
   $(this).find(".name").css("color","yellow") 
    //if you want to change background color
    $(this).find(".name").css("background","yellow")
});
```

Comment: jsQuery would be overkill in this case. And you only implemented half of the solution.

Comment: $(".pdf-icon-box").hover(function(){
   $(this).find(".name").css("color","yellow") 
    //if you want to change background color
    $(this).find(".name").css("background","yellow")
}).mouseout(function(){$(this).find(".name").css("background-color","green");});  . this is the full solution and I am not sure why jquery "would be overkill ".