# Modifying multiple results by class name?

Tags: javascript

How would I go about selecting each element in the script below, modifying the innerHTML by adding +5, and then re-writing the old number with the new one?

The code below when the JavaScript runs would put out 15, 25, 35 when modified by +5.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="test">10</div>
<div class="test">20</div>
<div class="test">30</div>

<script>
    ?
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Was able to do this with the help received. Using PHP I will write timestamps to template files and then using Javascript I will fetch each timestamp and then format the time and convert it to the users timezone.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p class="time">1408917668</p>
<p class="time">1378917668</p>

<script>
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("time");
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {

    // get elements timestamp
    var time = parseInt(elems[i].innerHTML);

    // convert timestamp to miliseconds
    var d = new Date(time * 1000);

    // out put the modified timestamp
    elems[i].innerHTML = d;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not a code-writing service. You need to show that you've done some research, and made some stab at solving the problem, and then ask a particular question about what you need help with, or where you're stuck.

Comment: By "need", I meant that this site has certain [rules and conventions](http://stackoverflow.com/help) about what constitutes a ["good"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["on topic"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. In particular, this site is designed to accumulate answers that *will be useful to others in future*, rather than small snippets of code that solve a momentary problem for a single user. Do not take downvotes as a judgement on you personally; rather, they are a measure of how well the question fits the purpose of the site.

Comment: So you are saying no person else in the world will ever wonder how to select the results of multiple elements by their class name, modify the results, and then overwrite the original innerHTML with the new innerHTML?

You think I REALLY am coding a script to just modify numbers by +5? Or its just a basic example so others could learn from it?

Comment: Well, you are actually combining three separate things here: how to select elements by class name; how to parse the text of those results to manipulate them mathematically (implied by the +5); and how to overwrite the text with a new value. If you had broken down the problem, you might have found [an answer to the first part](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478942/get-element-by-using-class-name) and been able to provide partial code if you were then stuck on the second.

Comment: I would apologise for my initial comment being slightly blunt - I do normally try to "assume good faith", as they say on Wikipedia - but your complete over-reaction since suggests it wouldn't have made much difference what I said.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the set of elements, parse the number, add, and write it out

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    var num = parseInt(elems[i].innerHTML);
    elems[i].innerHTML = num + 5;
}
```